# AWS CloudFront not updating with newer content

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I've hosted a website on S3, with CloudFront over the top. Now I've changed some code and try to update the newer content but I'm unable to achieve it.
I read somewhere that after invalidation it works but in my case even after invalidation I'm unable to update it.
Could someone please tell me the exact steps to update the new content in CloudFront?

Comment: After invalidating with the wildcard `/**` reload your page with CTRL+F5 which is a hard reload. Does it still show outdated data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to be sure that you're using a wildcard character or explicitly invalidating the object you updated. After the invalidation completes, you need to do a hard reload of your webpage by pressing CTRL+F5 (Thanks Tom) or open the window in private browsing. This will ensure your local cache isn't the issue.

[CloudFront Invalidation Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8Sv5.png)

Here's some documentation from AWS regarding invalidations.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html

Comment: Thank you Danvari for your response. So, should I update it after invalidation or first I update and then invalidate the cache?

Comment: In short: What should I do after invalidation? I've already updated by the same procedure you mentioned but its not updating.

Comment: As Tom Nijs mentioned above, you need to do a hard reload by pressing CTRL+F5. Alternatively, you could try opening the webpage in private browsing mode (incognito in Chrome) to see if the changes took effect and to rule out your local browser's cache being an issue.

Comment: Thank you Danvari. I got your answer.